# How to use test cards for Google Play Billing for an Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso, in-app-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I am hoping to write an Espresso test to test the payments flow in my app which uses Google Play Billing. I want to use the test cards provided as part of the [application licensing flow](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777), but I believe the device needs to be logged into the Play Store with a licensed tester email address in order to access this flow. Any idea how I could set this up as part of the test environment?